# Refresh my Highcharts graph in real time with database data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I currently have a problem with my Highcharts chart. So here I am, recovering my data which is in the database via a **values.php** file which is below :

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=didatec;charset=utf8', 'root', ''); //Connexion

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT date, temperature, consommation FROM acquisition, caisson, experience "; //Requête SQL 

foreach  ($bdd->query($sql) as $row) {
echo $row['date'] . "/" . $row['temperature']. "/" . $row['consommation']. "/"  ; //Récupère "time" et "degres" dans la base

}
?>
```

The data is recovered in this form:

> Time/Temperature/Consumption

So I get a result on my values.php page in this form :

> 2018-06-06 08:21:31/45/6/2018-06-07 00:00:00/89/24/2018-06-06
>   09:41:51/64/20/2018-06-08 10:19:46/20/6/2018-06-08
>   11:25:12/30/2/2018-06-08 13:38:08/60/8/2018-06-08
>   14:11:49/25/12/2018-06-08 15:09:00/59/15/

In order this gives:

> ```
> 2018-06-06 08:21:31 //Time
> 45 //Temperature
> 6 //Consumption
> ```

The data are then cut by a slash allowing me to integrate them then on my graph. I currently have a differed graph that works very well like that. I would like to do almost the same but in real life. That is to say that with each new data in base, the graph refreshes every second and displays the data to me on the graph. Currently, my graph refreshes every second but recovers data from who knows where. Here is my data.js file where is my real-time graph (below). I tried a few things, but I didn't get anything convincing. So I'd like a little help since I've been on it for a week. I'm sure it's a stupid mistake too. By thanking you!

**My file data.js :**

```
$(function() {

var date = []; //time
var C1_Temp = [];   //degres
var C1_Deci =[];
var switch1 = true;
$.get('values.php', function(data) { //Récupère les données extraites de la base de données

    data = data.split('/');

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
      date.push(data[i]);
      C1_Temp.push(parseFloat(data[i + 1]));
      C1_Deci.push(parseFloat(data[i + 2]));
    }

    date.pop();

    $('#chartLive').highcharts({ //Déclaration du graphique avec sa configuration

        chart : {
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in IE < IE 10.
            type : 'spline', //Type de courbe 
            events:{
                load: function (){

                var chart = this;

                var series = this.series[0];
                var series1 = this.series[1];


                setInterval(function (){

                    // var x = (new Date()).getTime();

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 3) {
                        date.push(data[i]);
                        var y = C1_Temp.push(parseFloat(data[i + 1]));
                        var z = C1_Deci.push(parseFloat(data[i + 2]));
                     }


                    series.addPoint([y], true);
                    series.addPoint([z], true);

                }, 3000);

                // chart.redraw(data);

                }
            }
        },
        title : {
            text : 'Graphique en différé' //Titre du graphique
        },
        subtitle : {
            text : 'Températures et décibels' //Texte en haut hors graph
        },
        xAxis : { //Axe horizontal
            title : {
                text : 'Date'
            },
            categories : date,
            // max: 5,
            // min: 0,
        },
        yAxis : { //Axe vertical
            title : {
                text : 'Températures et décibels', //Texte à gauche hors graph
            },
        },
        tooltip : {
            crosshairs : true,
            shared : true,
            valueSuffix : ''
        },
        plotOptions : {
            spline : {
                marker : {
                    radius : 4,
                    lineColor : '#666666',
                    lineWidth : 1
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false //permet de cacher le lien du graph en bas à droite
        },
        series : [{

            name : 'Températures', //Ajout de la courbe pour la température
            data : C1_Temp
        },{

            name : 'Décibels',
            data : C1_Deci

        }]
    });


    }); 
});
```

Comment: If someone who's an expert on the subject could help me, that would be really nice.

Comment: It seems that you fetch the data from php file (`getJSON`) only once. Then you launch `setInterval` that always operates on **the same** data set. So you basically add the same data every 3 seconds. Here's an example that uses promises to handle ajax call in `setInterval` - you can try this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/dv74ze6n/

Comment: Thank you @KamilKulig . The only little thing I don't understand is with data and await. Never having used that, I think it's going to be complicated for me right now. If you have an example code to show me based on mine, I'm a taker. By thanking you!

Comment: Here's a simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/paLk0e1c/